# Would apprenticeships improve the economy long term?

Tags: macroeconomics, public-economics, soft-question, education-economics

Evening my name is Nick and I am a high school student from Fairfield California and I’m 17, my super hyper theatrical question is about a substitute to college in order to create more efficiency in the economy.

Much of Europe has “apprenticeships” along with colleges however the studies I have been able to read have shown more efficiency in apprentices rather than college graduates.  My ideas is that if we could have businesses ensnare a more extreme internship “apprenticeships” not only will we be able to ensure a new and younger work force in the United States but help with student debt.

By working directly for the company you would be able to learn the SPECIFIC skills one would need for that job and utilize it probably much earlier then a college graduate. With Bachelor degrees taking an average of 4 years for most studies and masters being 6 the amount of time is really holding back a potential young labor force and many of those whom I have studied and Kent in my personal life that have graduated college have said I learned after I got my job only my FIRST year of college taught me what I needed to understand before I got into my profession these people I’ve lent being architects, engineers, managers and more.

So in order to have a better labor force for certain jobs I believe it would be advisable to instate the young labor force after high school as an avail race option to company’s carrying there professions. This would also solver the student debt crisis which only holds down the young labor force even more and while apprenticeship would still create a debt learning a profession for free without getting paid would be much more beneficial then colleges option of not being paid and having to pay massive amounts of money in order to achieve ones professions. In order to convince companies of this I would propose tax right offs and subsidies to companies which due so and increased taxes on those who don’t.

After a period of time I believe 8-12 years progress should be observed by that point and depending on results the decision of whether or not to keep this new apprenticeship system would be worth the tax right offs and government subsidies in order to decide whether or not to continue. If No then it will just become a concept that fades away over time and if yes the government will utilize it. 
However abolishing college is my last goal but college does have an extreme control on the future labor force which is why I propose this. College surplus can buy time to manage themselves and profession found not very effective with apprenticeships will remain college dominant keeping colleges around.

I say all this because my profession I wish to achieve is petroleum engineering and the dozens I have spoke to at chevron and shell all had similar answers after about my first two years of college I was ready to start learning what my company specifically teaches me everything else I learned was just inefficient at least in the sense of benefiting the majority of engineers in my field, and this does not just only apply to petroleum engineers. So ultimately I just find this idea to seek a balance of college and apprenticeships, jobs which are capable of very easily teaching its own new employed everything they need to specifically know and understand in order to achieve efficiency for there industry or firm especially with government assistance and those that differ to probably remain in college. I believe this balance would both improve the economy in long run and secure a younger, more efficient labor force for the United States.

However my fears have predicted a few errors, one being if companies simply do not apply because at the time of doing this the content may be at full employment possibly. Another fear being if the transaction is to fast and college surplus or even default money supply runs out to quickly causing shut downs across the country thus completely running the future workforce. The last fear I’ve been able to think of is that with company creating more efficient employees threw specific trading if the company were to go out of business then mass structural unemployment could develop unless easy adaption happens to be available but now seems more unlikely by not achieving college degrees.

Thank you so much for taking the time to read my long idea it’s just been what I have been able to comprise together as a long term economic theory to help grow the economy threw a hopefully more efficient and younger labor force, a reply would be amazing for feedback I would love to hear.

Comment: Paragraphs were a great invention to help readability.  That being said, you are correct that there are serious issues with the design of US higher education

Comment: Can you please make your actual question more specific? This is usually not a forum to exchange opinions.

Comment: Linking to the studies you have read may also help clarify what you mean.

Comment: P.S.: I teach in the EU and I hear about how much better the US graduate system is all the time. (It is likely that the anecdotes are only valid for the top x% of US schools.)

Comment: I do not have a definitive answer or data to provide some insights but two things came to mind when reading your idea. First is that many of the high paying jobs require highly specialized skill that requires way more than the 2 first years of college (for example jobs that require data analysis skills). The second is that apprenticeships create both risks for the companies to invest in a person that might leave the company after being trained, and also might create dependability for the young person on the company and maybe lose the flexibility to later move to another job if needed.